# Add class to one list item based on its innerHtml

Tags: jquery, innerhtml

I want to use jQuery to set a class on one list item based on its innerHtml value matching the innerHtml value of a span.

I have managed to write the following code:

```js
if ($(".number").text() === "1") {
      $("li:eq(0)").addClass("selected");
    }
    if ($(".number").text() === "2") {
      $("li:eq(1)").addClass("selected");
    }
    if ($(".number").text() === "3") {
      $("li:eq(2)").addClass("selected");
    }
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: #dFd;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="number">2</span> <ul id="menu"> <li>1</li> <li>2</li> <li>3</li> </ul>
```

However, I feel as though it could be made more efficient and written more neatly. How can I improve this code?

Comment: Get the int value of the text as $i,  then you can use the value in a selector eg: $("li:eq(" + ($i-1) + ")")

Comment: Migration to Code Review was rejected due to lack of clarity. This looks like a stripped-down example. What are you really trying to accomplish? Your question says "…matching the **innerHtml** value of a span", but your code actually calls **`.text()`**, not `.html()`. Furthermore, you say you want to choose "one list item based on its **innerHtml**", but you are actually choosing an item based on its position. Please clarify those discrepancies, and also add more context about what this code is for (see [How to Ask](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) on Code Review).

Comment: Hi, Requirement is based on the number written in span, i have to add a class. if No. 1 is written then add class on first list, if no 2 is written then add class on second list. It has to be in loop:

<div class="quantity-select">
<span class="number">2</span>
<ul id="menu">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>
</div>

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get rid of all the `if`s by first getting the selected value into a variable, and then using that as a parameter when setting the class:

```
var selected = parseInt($(".number").text(), 10) - 1;
$("li:eq("+selected+")").addClass("selected");
```

Note that if you wish to limit the value to `1..3`, as in your example, you must have `if (selected >= 1 && selected <= 3)` before setting the class.

Comment: Hi Antti,
Would be a great help if you tell me how to put the below script in looP:

var selected = parseInt($(".number").html(), 10) - 1;
$('.number').parent(".quantity-select").find("li:eq("+selected+")").addClass("selected");

Comment: @SameerAli: My earlier reply got lost in the migration attempt. I think your best bet is to ask a new question.